# C++/CLI Graphics->DrawArc(DrawLine) in loop clear

Tags: winforms, graphics, c++-cli, drawing

Problem: I have collection of CircleSegment, when i trying to draw them all at PictureBox, i receive only last CircleSegment from collection on pictureBox. Why?

```
ref class CircleSegment 
    {
    public:
        array<double>^ massive;
        Pen^ Blackpen;
        int index;
         CircleSegment^ SegmentCircleCollection::operator [] ( const int a ) 
     { 
         return this->Alfa[a];
     }
    ....
    }


ref class SegmentCircleCollection
{
    public:
    Generic::List<CircleSegment^> ^Alfa;
...
}


private: System::Void pictureBox1_Paint(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventArgs^  e) 
 {   
   //Where SegmentCircleCollection^ myCollection;
   for each(CircleSegment^ Selected in myCollection->Alfa)
       {
           e->Graphics->DrawLine(Selected->Blackpen,(int)Selected->massive[6],(int)Selected->massive[7],(int)Selected->massive[8],(int)Selected->massive[9]);
            e->Graphics->DrawArc(Selected->Blackpen,(int)Selected->massive[0],(int)Selected->massive[1],(int)Selected->massive[2],(int)Selected->massive[3],(int)Selected->massive[4],(int)Selected->massive[5]);
       }
```

...

}

Comment: Good odds that your list is filled with CircleSegments that are all the same.  Which points at a bug in the code that fills the list, forgetting to use the gcnew operator is a common bug.  Use the debugger.

Comment: I was check that already, points in massive are different in each CircleSegment